# Read properties from properties file in a regular interval at runtime

Tags: java, spring, properties-file

There are some properties, and I want to read these properties in an interval, and if there is any update in the properties, I am taking some action on that basis.

```
    @Value("${sms.smpp.country.list:{}}")
    private String smppCountryList;

    @Value("${sms.smpp.country.config.list:{}}")
    private String smppCountryConfigList;

    @Value("${sms.smpp.properties.file.location:{}}")
    private String propertiesFileLocation;
```

I have written a code to read the properties using cron, here is the code.

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/7 * * * ?")
    public Properties readPropertiesFile() {
        Properties prop = null;
        
        try (InputStream input = new FileInputStream(propertiesFileLocation)) {
            prop = new Properties();
            prop.load(input);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            logger.info("[SMPP] [CONFIG CRON] Exception occurred while reading the properties file: [{}]",ex.getMessage());
        }
        
        return prop;
    }
```

The code is getting called by the cron, or I can also write an onFileChangeHandler on the file.

But is there any easy and elegant way to do this, like can this be handled by spring?

Comment: in your current solution, are the attributes annotated by `@Value` automatically refreshed ? I'd say no, but I wonder.

Comment: @RUARO Thibault No, the values are not getting refreshed, but after reading the properties file I am updating those values.

Answer (score 1):

Edit 1: Looking at your code i want to point one thing that @Value variables won't be updated with updated value even if you continuously run cron job

If you regularly want to look for configuration changes Spring Boot comes with a spring config server.

Your micro service will be up to date with the configuration without writing any lines to code.

Have a look a Spring Cloud Config Server

Comment: I am updating the @Value variables after reading it using cron.

Comment: Try Spring cloud Config Server(Spring recommend doing this way), can you share how you are updating the value

Comment: I am updating the value like this:

```smppCountryList = readPropertiesFile.get(sms.smpp.country.list)```

Comment: This would be lots of manual work. Today it's one file when it will be 1000 then it will create lots of problem. I would suggest don't do this way and use Spring Cloud Config Server. If it helps do vote!!

Comment: Yes @Shivendra, Spring Cloud Config Server will help but I cannot use it, I wanted to know some other way like some annotation or config change or anything like that.

Comment: According to me their is no other way and annotations. Things have to be completely Spring based or Java. In your case you are mixing core Java loading of properties with Spring boot. Do it either complete Spring which is Spring Cloud Config for core Java make map and fetch, reload values from that map

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Spring Config Server and if you want to update property annotated with @Value, you need to annotate the class with @RefreshScope.